# How to get frequency of each string across multiple sets of strings by sets

Tags: python, dataframe, pivot-table

I have a text file for each set as below

```
Set1: Cow Goat Lion Mole

Set2: Mole Badger Snake

Set3: Goat Snake Zebra
```

My aim is to get a matrix of distribution of each unique value across sets and a total count for each value

```
        S1 S2 S3  Total
Goat     Y  N Y   ....2

Snake    N  Y Y   ....2
```

At the outset it may look like an excel problem but the data set is large and i am not sure a pivot table can do this. My approach would be in python but i am new and looking for advice on best approach
-read each csv to dataframe (concat?)
-find unique values across all columns (store in a df?)
-run iteration for each unique value to get frequency
-i am not sure how would i then keep track of set count and then produce the tabular output i want
-tx

Comment: What did you do so far? What part of the coding you have a problem with? Also, you speak of CSV, but the sample input you provide is not CSV?

Comment: Please reformat your question such that relations between the data involved are apparent.

Comment: I edited , hope it is clearer now

Comment: Your input and expected output format is still not clear. I suggest reading [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and editing the question accordingly. I thought first that this was a [pandas question](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html), but it seems you do not want to use this library which makes this task rather simple.

Comment: I will try again.  I've 'n' text files, lets call each of them a set. Set has a list of words and some words are present in several sets while some are unique to a set. I want to find out  1. All the unique words across the sets and then 2. for each unique word find how many sets contain that word.  So in my original question i want to  obtain that  'Goat' is present in sets 1 and 3 and total sets that contain goat are 2.   In my case each list is going into 1000 +  words and there are several sets . I would not mind using pandas, though would appreciate some hints. whatever gives a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import necessary packages

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob
```

Set Path where all your .txt files are

```
path = r'C:\rawdata_files'                     # use your path
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.txt"))     # advisable to use os.path.join as this makes concatenation OS independent
```

The list would look something like below:

```
all_files = ['val1.txt', 'val2.txt']
```

Make a df with name of text file as column and entries as rows

```
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(item, names=[item[:-4]]) for item in all_files], axis=1) ##-4 is done as you would not need .txt as your column name
```

Get the total value for every element  across columns:

```
df.stack().value_counts()
```

Comment: tx Rahul , on it now

Comment: If you found the answer helpful..do upvote and accept

Comment: @user10701663: Does it worked?

Comment: yes it helped. Thank you